# missing right parenthesis-oracle

Tags: oracle

```
create table sl_rep_winners(
    slnum INT (12),
    zone INT, 
    city nvarchar(200), 
    county nvarchar(200), 
    town nvarchar(200)
);
```

I get a "missing right parenthesis" error. What is the reason of error?

Comment: what is your dbms - oracle or mysql?

Comment: Your SQL code runs fine on mySQL. The source of your problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Oracle: use nvarchar2() (not: nvarchar)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when I wrote my comment the post was tagged with both mySQL and Oracle. It has been edited then by Mat, but are we sure that Gokce Ezeroglu indeed uses Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle:

```
create table sl_rep_winners 
(    
    slnum number(12), 
    zone number(10), 
    city varchar2(200), 
    county varchar2(200), 
    town varchar2(200)
);
```

INTEGER is supported as an ANSI datatype but gets converted to the equivalent Oracle datatype which is number().

FYI:
[nvarchar & varchar2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18325223/10457877)

Comment: It might be worth noting that `number(12)` supports a maximum value of `999999999999` which is much larger than the maximum value supported by MySQL's `int` data type.